# Row delimiter change while writing a tsv file in adls gen 1 from databrick

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-functions, databricks

I want to save the tsv file to adls gen1. Using the below command to save the data but it writing a row delimiter as "\n"(LF) I want to writing a row delimiter  "\r\n"

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").options(delimiter="\t",header="true",nullValue= None,lineSep ='\r\n').save(gen1temp)
```

I am having a 400+columns and 2M rows and file size in 6GB.
Please help with optimal solumn.

Answer (score 1):

support for `lineSep`  option for CSV files exists only in [Spark 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv), and doesn't exist in the earlier versions, like, [2.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv), so it simply ignored.

Initially I thought about following workaround - append `\r` to the last column:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit

data = spark.range(1, 100).withColumn("abc", col("id")).withColumn("def", col("id"))
cols = map(lambda cn: col(cn), data.schema.fieldNames())
cols[-1] = concat(cols[-1].cast("string"), lit("\r"))
data.select(cols).write.csv("1.csv")
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work - it looks like that it's stripping ending whitespace when writing data into CSV...

Comment: I am facing same problem for one of the requirement... Using spark 2.4 and not sure how to get this thing \r\n at the end